# React Native - Multithreading

Tags: reactjs, multithreading, react-native, amazon-s3

I have a mobile app built using react-native.
With this app, user takes hundreds of photos
The photos need to be uploaded to S3 ASAP
Wondering if react-native supports multithreading so that we can process uploads faster

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use z.B. [react-native-workers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-workers).